# facebook ios api - How to send a synchronous graph request

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

In ios 6 using facebook ios sdk 3.5 how can I send a graph request so it's synchornious? Or atleast how can I synchronize the response method?

I'm using the following method:

```
+(void)hasUserGrantedPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                        andBlock:(void (^)(bool))repeatBlock{
    [[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, FBGraphObject* result, NSError *error) {
         if([[result valueForKey:@"data"] count] <1){
             repeatBlock(false);
         }

         FBGraphObject* grantedPerms = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
         for(NSString* requestedPerm in permissions){
             if (! [grantedPerms valueForKey:requestedPerm]){
                 repeatBlock(true);
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

How can I alter the method or request in such a way that it becomes synchronous?

Thank you

Comment: Why? The whole API is designed to be asynchronous/task/completion based. AFAIK there is no way for it. Just continue execution on completion handler.